# Regex expression to strip ending of word

Tags: python, regex

I have the following identifiers:

```
id1 = '883316040119_FRIENDS_HD'
id2 = 'ZWEX01DE9463DB_DMD' 
id3 = '35358fr1'
id4 = 'as3d99j_br001'
```

I need a regex to get me the following output:

```
id1 = '883316040119'
id2 = 'ZWEX01DE9463DB' 
id3 = '35358'
id4 = 'as3d99j'
```

Here is what I have so far --

```
re.sub(r'_?([a-zA-Z]{2,4}?\d?(00\d)?)$','',vendor_id)
```

It doesn't work perfectly though, here is what it gives me:

```
BAD  - 883316040119_FRIENDS
GOOD - ZWEX01DE9463DB
GOOD - 35358
GOOD - as3d99j
```

What would be the correct regular expression to get all of them? For the first one, I basically want to strip the ending if it is only underscores and letters, so `1928h9829_bundle_hd --> 1928h9829`.

Please note that I have hundreds of thousands of identifiers here, and it is required that I use a regular expression. I'm not looking for a python `split()` way to do it, as it wouldn't work.

Comment: What qualifies as "ending of a word"?

Comment: What would be the result for `abcd4343`? Also, why not check first if the text contains a `_` and then apply your expression?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive and tell what exactly is it that you want to remain in your resulting strings.

Comment: your expression seems to fail for `'35358fr1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the examples:

```
for id in ids :
    print (id)

883316040119_FRIENDS_HD
ZWEX01DE9463DB_DMD
35358fr1
as3d99j_br001

for id in ids :
    hit = re.sub( "(_[A-Za-z_]*|_?[A-Za-z]{2,4}?\d?(00\d)?)$", "", id)
    print (hit)

883316040119
ZWEX01DE9463DB
35358
as3d99j
```

When the tail contains letters and underscores, then the pattern is easygoing and strips off any number of underscores and digits; if the tail does not contain an underscore, or contains digits after the underscore, then it demands the pattern in the question: 0/2/3/4 letters then an optional digit then an optional zero-zero-digit.

Answer (score 2):

The way you present your input, I would suggest this simple regex:

```
^(?:[^_]+(?=_)|\d+)
```

This can be tweaked if you want to add details to the spec.

To show you a regex demo, just because of the way the site regex101 works, we have to add `\n` (it assumes we are working on the whole file, rather than one input at a time): **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tU4fQ4/1)**

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The non-capture group `(?: ... )` matches either
- `[^_]+(?=_)` non-underscore characters (followed by an underscore, not matched)
- `|` OR
- `\d+` digits

Comment: For the `35358fr1` line, I have assumed that we only want digits. If you have a different way to express the delimiter, let me know and I will tweak it. :)

Comment: I like this because its a good starting point and can be added to later, gets my +1.

Comment: Simple and beautiful!

Comment: Thank you, @dvm. It looks like David picked a different idea—matching (and removing) the suffix instead of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for underscore only one possible time, as `?` means `{0,1}`.

```
r'(_[a-zA-Z]{2,}\d?(00[0-9])?|[a-z]{2,}\d)+$'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though that doesn't work on the second id now.

Comment: @David542 just updated the answer, it is not really elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

The following reproduces your desired results from your input.

I would use the replace method with this regex:

```
_[^']+|(?!.*_)('[0-9]+)[^']+
```

and return capturing group 1

Perhaps:

```
result = re.sub("_[^']+|(?!.*_)('[0-9]+)[^']+", r"\1", subject)
```

The regex first looks for an underscore.  If it finds one, it will match everything up to but not including the next single quote; and that will get removed.

If that doesn't match, the alternative will look for a string that does NOT have an underscore; match and return in capturing group 1 the sequence of digits; and then replace everything after the digits up to but not including the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

This is not subtraction approach. Just capture matched string.

The regex is `^[0-9]+)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=_)`.(ie `(^\d+)|(^[\d\w]+(?=_))`)

```
import re
id1 = '883316040119_FRIENDS_HD'
id2 = 'ZWEX01DE9463DB_DMD' 
id3 = '35358fr1'
id4 = 'as3d99j_br001'
ids = [id1, id2, id3, id4]

for i in ids:
    try:
        print re.match(r"(^[0-9]+)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=_))", i).group()
    except:
        print "not matched"
```

output:

```
883316040119
ZWEX01DE9463DB
35358
as3d99j
```